# How can I add black navbar to the existing transparent navbar?

Tags: html, css, angular, bootstrap-4, navbar

Does anyone have an idea how can I add black navbar below "some text" in navbar shown below? It doesn't matter how this navbar will look like I would like to have it just across the entire width of the screen below the string `Some text`. Any ideas?

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg fixed-top navbar-transparent" color-on-scroll="500">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="navbar-translate">
      <button class="navbar-toggler navbar-burger" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarToggler"
              aria-controls="navbarTogglerDemo02" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation"
              (click)="sidebarToggle()">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-bar"></span>
        <span class="navbar-toggler-bar"></span>
        <span class="navbar-toggler-bar"></span>
      </button>
    </div>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarToggler">


      <div class="outer">
        <div class="middle">
          <div class="inner">
            <br><br><br>
            <h6 align="center">Some text</h6>
            <div class="black-bar" style="width: 100vw; height: 80px; background-color: white"></div>

          </div>
        </div>
      </div>


      <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
        <li class="nav-item" *ngIf="!isDocumentation() && !isMain()">
          <a class="nav-link" rel="tooltip" title="Follow us on Twitter" data-placement="bottom"
             href="https://twitter.com/CreativeTim" target="_blank">
            <i class="fa fa-twitter"></i>
            <p class="d-lg-none">Twitter</p>
          </a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item" *ngIf="!isDocumentation() && !isMain()">
          <a class="nav-link" rel="tooltip" title="Like us on Facebook" data-placement="bottom"
             href="https://www.facebook.com/CreativeTim" target="_blank">
            <i class="fa fa-facebook-square"></i>
            <p class="d-lg-none">Facebook</p>
          </a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item" *ngIf="!isDocumentation() && !isMain()">
          <a class="nav-link" rel="tooltip" title="Follow us on Instagram" data-placement="bottom"
             href="https://www.instagram.com/CreativeTimOfficial" target="_blank">
            <i class="fa fa-instagram"></i>
            <p class="d-lg-none">Instagram</p>
          </a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item" *ngIf="!isDocumentation() && !isMain()">
          <a class="nav-link" rel="tooltip" title="Star on GitHub" data-placement="bottom"
             href="https://www.github.com/CreativeTimOfficial/pk2-angular" target="_blank">
            <i class="fa fa-github"></i>
            <p class="d-lg-none">GitHub</p>
          </a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item" *ngIf="!isDocumentation()">
          <a href="http://pk2-angular.creative-tim.com/documentation/tutorial" class="nav-link" target="_blank"><i
            class="nc-icon nc-book-bookmark"></i> Documentation</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item" *ngIf="!isHome()">
          <a [routerLink]="['/home']" *ngIf="!isDocumentation()" class="nav-link"><i class="nc-icon nc-layout-11"></i>Components</a>
          <a [routerLink]="['/home']" *ngIf="isDocumentation()" class="nav-link">Back to Kit</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item" *ngIf="isDocumentation()">
          <a href="https://github.com/creativetimofficial/pk-free-angular/issues?ref=pk2-free-local" target="_blank"
             class="nav-link">Have an issue</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

It looks [in this way](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c6VQK.png) after adding `<div class="black-bar" style="width: 100vw; height: 80px; background-color: white"></div>` after h6:

Comment: It's hard to tell what you are trying to do, but if you want a black background to your navbar, just do...

`.navbar {
  background-color:black;
}`

Comment: I have a transparent navbar with `"some text"` in the middle. I would like add black navbar below. Do you know how can I do this?

Comment: Here is what I think you are trying to accomplish. Add this after the <h6> line.

`<div class="black-bar" style="width: 100vw; height: 80px; background-color: black"></div>`

Comment: @Brian I updated the question with current view. I changed only `background-color:` to white to make it visible. It looks good on the right side because it touches the right side of the screen. There is only a problem with left side, do you know how can I change it to be like on the right side?

Comment: Please post all relevant code, so that we could see what you are seeing.  What you have posted so far isn't enough to replicate what you are seeing.

Comment: @user9645789 You will need to provide the CSS that goes with this HTML so we know what you are seeing!

Comment: @Mers I updated source code.

Comment: @Brian I updated source code.

Comment: If you are having issues with it not working around your margins on your document, you can try just setting the div to position:absolute, left:0, right:0, and setting a height. I will put it in the answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could put a div underneath the < h6 > tag. Something like this..

```
<div class="black-bar" style="height:100px; background-color: black; position:absolute; left:0; right:0;"></div>
```

Hope this works for you!

Comment: I tried in this way before but it also didn't help. I updated screenshot with current view.

Comment: If you can provide the full code, I can do a better job of helping you. You will need to post any CSS/JS that goes with the HTML you posted above.

Comment: I solved my problem. I used your code in another place. Thank you for your support.

Answer (score 0):

If you're just needing a black line under the "some text", why not do something like:

```
h6 {
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    border-bottom: solid 80px black;
}
```

Comment: Because I need to have input text field in navbar and it doesn't work. If I use it there is a quite similar situation as in the screenshot added to the first question.